# Does AsParallel work with Enumerable methods?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, plinq

I wrote this code to check if AsParallel() can make enumerable methods work faster.
After removing AsParallel() I get comparable times, so I would to ask you:
am I doing something wrong or AsParallel works only with query-like approach in PLINQ?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listt = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 999999; i++)
            listt.Add(i);

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.FFF"));

        for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
            qq(listt);

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.FFF"));
    }

    static void qq(List<int> listt)
    { 
        var l = listt.AsParallel().Where(x => x%2 == 0);
        int q = l.FirstOrDefault(); //added after question has been posted
        q = q + 3;
    }
```

Edit:
I just added int q = l.FirstOrDefault();  and q = q + 3 into qq method to use "l" variable and AsParallel version works even slover.
In this site they said that AsParallel can make execution slow if number of elements are relativelly small, but listt contains 999999 elements.
https://www.dotnetperls.com/asparallel
Can someone explain why it slows down?

Comment: Be aware that `List<T>` isn't thread safe so you could end up with some quite strange results if you're not careful. Better to use `ConcurrentBag<T>` for example.

Comment: Your `var l = ...` is never enumerated so you have benchmarked __nothing against nothing__ and you only learned that benchmarking is much harder than it looks.

Comment: On the same theme, `x%2 == 0` is way too small as a workload.

Comment: @DavidG - no, this is the proper use of `IEnumerable<T>.AsParallel()` so please don't use a Concurrent collection here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman As long as the body is thread safe, then yes. That's why I said OP "could" end up with issues.

Comment: There is no real body here but that should not use the `listt.` source anyway. I just didn't want to let the suggestion of using `ConcurrentBag.AsParallel()` stand, that only makes sense in  very rare and exceptional cases.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` was a bad pick as it tries to minimize the enumeration. You are still not benching anything real. Try `.Sum()` instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried to use "int q = l.Sum();" instead of "int q = l.FirstOrDefault();" and still version with AsParallel works twenty times slower :(

Comment: Yes, benchmarking is very hard. Benchmarking parallelism is even harder.